# TensorRT Error:[context.cpp::setStream::121] Error Code 1: Cudnn (CUDNN_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR)

Tags: python, tensorrt

When I use the tensorRT inference code officially provided by NVIDIA

```
# This function is generalized for multiple inputs/outputs.
# inputs and outputs are expected to be lists of HostDeviceMem objects.
def do_inference(context, bindings, inputs, outputs, stream, batch_size=1):
    # Transfer input data to the GPU.
    [cuda.memcpy_htod_async(inp.device, inp.host, stream) for inp in inputs]
    # Run inference.
    context.execute_async(batch_size=batch_size, bindings=bindings, stream_handle=stream.handle)
    # Transfer predictions back from the GPU.
    [cuda.memcpy_dtoh_async(out.host, out.device, stream) for out in outputs]
    # Synchronize the stream
    stream.synchronize()
    # Return only the host outputs.
    return [out.host for out in outputs]
```

Everytime when i run the code here,

```
context.execute_async(batch_size=batch_size, bindings=bindings, stream_handle=stream.handle)
```

i will get the error message

> [TRT] [E] 1: [context.cpp::setStream::121] Error Code 1: Cudnn (CUDNN_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this error when you start running?

```
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:2981] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
```

If so, downgrade your Tensorflow from 2.10 to 2.9.2.
See more at: https://github.com/google-research/multinerf/issues/47

Hope it helps!

Comment: Don't link to the solution, provide it in your answer.